# Printing in awk up to specific line and 5 more results

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm trying to print out all the lines up to the appearance of a particular song and 5 more songs with that. The problem i'm new to the shell what I have to fix in the bellow commands?

```
RANK  NAME                    BAND  YEAR   GENERE  DOMESTIC/INTERNATIONAL   
206:Reach Out, I'll Be There:The Four Tops:1978:Pop:3/2         
207:Bye Bye Love:The Everly Brothers:1950:Classic:3/2     
208:Gloria:Them:1965:Classic:1/1      
209:In My Room:The Beach Boys:1985:Classic:5/7  
210:96 Tears:? & the Mysterians:1964:Classic:20/15     
211:Caroline, No:The Beach Boys:1975:Classic:5/7   
212:1999:Prince:1958:Classic:5/7       
213:Your Cheatin' Heart:Hank Williams:1988:Soul:7/6
```

```
awk '{print * "For What It's Worth"} ' songs            
awk '/For What It's Worth/, {print $1 $2}' songs
```

Comment: Can you try explaining this a bit more, it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @slm  I want a command to print out all the lines up to "Caroline, No" and 5 songs after that.                        like print from the beginning up to song name "Caroline" and 5 more songs (lines) after that.

Comment: In general: If you ask something like that then you should **always** provide example input and example output.

Comment: @Intermd11 - Also since you're pretty new to our site if you notice under your Q there's a edit link. You can refine your Q as you get feedback from others or if you want to expand it so that it better illustrates your problem. The comment you left me for example could be adapted into the Q.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed '/For What It.s Worth/{N;N;N;N;N;q}'
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what your attempted solution has to do with the problem you state; if your problem description is accurate the following should work

```
awk 'NR==1,/Caroline, No/{print;next};c++<5{print};' file
```

Comment: Probably easier to understand with `c++<5 {print}` (and adding the info that `{print}` is not necessary).

Comment: I appreciat it your help but what if I have a song named "For What It's Worth". probably that command will not work because the song name contain the symbol (It's).

Comment: @Intermd11, `awk "NR==1,/For What It's Worth/{print;next};c++<5{print}" file` should take care of it

Comment: @HaukeLaging, you are probably right, amended answer. I usually get upbraided on SO for being too verbose with `awk` but when it comes to newbies i see your point

Comment: @1_CR that actually worked, thank you for your assistance.